# Excel Table Fill multiple Value Between Two Table each one has a unique value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Table in Excel up to 54000 record

**Customer Table:**

| IdCust | Cooler 1 Nb | Cooler 2 Nb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1258 |  |  |
| 1222 |  |  |
| 3888 |  |  |
| 1188 |  |  |

**Coolers Table :**

| IdCooler | Customer Number | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5447 | 1188 |  |
| 3658 | 3888 |  |
| 2215 | 1188 |  |
| 2258 | 1258 |  |

I want to fill in the Customer Table Cooler 'x' nb with the CoolerID in Cooler Table
the Customer might have multiple Coolers up to 10 coolers The Customer Number=IdCust
IdCustomer is Unique Value
IdCooler Is Unique Value

Comment: Any way to determine which one will be in **Cooler 1 Nb** and the one in **Cooler 2 Nb** from coolers table?

Comment: If both IDs are numbers you can make a pivot with Average function. Keeping Customers in row, Coolers in Columns and cooler IDs as values with average function

Comment: Please **edit your question** to show what you have tried to solve this problem.  Understand that this is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with formulas or code you are trying to write.

Comment: I have tried to use the vlookup formula but it doesn't spill multiple result to determine Cooler 1 nb or Cooler 2 nb it doesn't make a difference the way the number is sorted

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vlookup to find any 'nth' number of matches in Excel.

You said you have up to 10 coolers in the coolers table, therefore, this code should work for you....

Alter the table names or ranges to suit your worksheet.

In cell B2 put the following formula (first cooler matching custID):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$9,SMALL(IF($A2=$H$2:$H$9,ROW($H$2:$H$9)-ROW($A2)+1),1)),"")
```

In cell B3 put the following formula (second cooler matching custID):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$9,SMALL(IF($A2=$H$2:$H$9,ROW($H$2:$H$9)-ROW($A2)+1),1)),"")
```

The last numerical value in the formula: -ROW($A2)+1),`1`)),"") tells Excel which nth value is required.

-ROW($A2)+1),`1`)),"") matches the first hit
-ROW($A2)+1),`2`)),"") matches the second hit
-ROW($A2)+1),`3`)),"") matches the third hit etc. etc.

[image]